# Should I launch a Thread to parse some xml?

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, parsing, handler

I'm kinda new to android development, but i'm trying to make a xml parser. I've been using android.sax library, following some tutos, and this works great.
One thing that is making me sceptical, is that I don't actually launch the parser in a separate thread, I just use a handlers to communicate between my parser and my main activity.
Should I parse in a Thread ?

Here's my main activity code :

```
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=AAAAABBBBBCCCCDDDEEEEFFF&country=FR&restrictBy=gtin=5030999075254&alt=atom");
        XMLHandler xHandler = new XMLHandler();
        Feed feed = xHandler.parse(url.openStream());

            if(feed.getTotalResults()==0 || feed.getItems() == null || feed.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                Log.w("XMLPARSENull", "No items
            }
            else {
                tv.setText(feed.getTotalResults()+" " + feed.getItemsPerPage() + " " + feed.getStartIndex() + " " + feed.getTitle());
                Iterator<Product> it = feed.getItems().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    Log.w("XMLPARSEFeed",it.next().getName());

                }
            }


    } catch(Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("XMLPARSEException", "ERROR",e);
    }
```

Comment: If you are starting out it could be wise to take a look at [StrictMode](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) - it tells you pretty quickly whenever you do something silly on a thread where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it's the parsing so much as the network operation, as any network request should not be performed in the UI thread.  You can either spawn a new `Thread` or an `AsyncTask` to perform your network request.  Here are some links to help:

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Expensive operations](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Designing for responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- [Thread documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer:
If you have connections in your main ( UI ) thread, the user interface will become frozen whilst the thread is used to download the information and parse it. It takes some time for a connection so it may appear to freeze.

Apart from that, android 4.0 now does not actually allow you to call HTTP requests from this thread, it will throw an error which will be seen in logcat before crashing.

It is best practise to use an Async Task here, here is some more information on that.
[Information on Async Tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is imperative that you move your parsing into a background thread, particularly if your XML is being streamed across the network; otherwise your app is likely to be killed off by the system for blocking the main thread.

You don't have to use a raw `Thread`, though; Android provides things like `ASyncTask` to make it a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Everything which isn't related to direct interaction with GUI should be moved to separate thread, prefferably AsyncTask if you need interaction with GUI from that thread since Android won't allow accessing GUI from regular Thread class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html